# logback not generating new log file

Tags: java, pom.xml, logback

I am using below logback.xml in my Micronaut project, it is not generating new log file as per rollingPolicy provided in xml configuration. I tried with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy and TimeBasedRollingPolicy but it did't worked.

Micronaut version: 1.2.2

logback-classic : 1.2.3

File: logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/my-app.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%cyan(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}):%line- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <fileNamePattern>
                logs/my-app.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%cyan(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}):%line- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong, your maxHistory policy is preventing you from building more than one file. Instead it deletes the old one and just creates a new one for the new day or when the 1mb in size is reached.

maxHistory in this case has to be combined with the TimeBasedRollingPolicy as you stated and maxHistory is the parameter for days then. Without the TimeBasedRollingPolicy it might just be the number of files.

Comment: In application we have provided maxHistory to 60, for posting a question I kept it to 1, (updated in question as well) Currently on server it is appending all logs to 1 file only and file size increased to GBs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience with logback, you should do something like:

```
<appender name="FILE"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
...
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/my-app.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>1MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
...
</appender>
```

Currently, you are using "**RollingFileAppender**" for policy, so it can't work.

Comment: Thanks Orcen, unfortunately it is also not working for me. :(

Comment: Did you tried to use `<maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>`  instead of `<totalSizeCap>1MB</totalSizeCap>` in your use case ? In fact totalSizeCap is saying that you would keep only 1MB of log over all your log file. 
Plus you can use **SizeBasedRollingPolicy** for your **rollingPolicy** and **RollingFileAppender** for your **appender**.

Source: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html